Unable to Sign Out with Keycloak using NextAuth in Next.js Application
Title: Setting Up NextAuth with Keycloak in Next.js 15.0.1
I'm trying to set up authentication for my Next.js application using NextAuth and Keycloak. My current setup includes:

Next.js: 15.0.1

NextAuth: 4.24.10

Keycloak: 25.x


Here’s my implementation:
File: pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth, { Session } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    id_token?: string;
    provider?: string;
    access_token?: string;
    refresh_token?: string;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      sub?: string;
      id?: string;
      access_token?: string;
      roles?: string[];
      name?: string;
      email?: string;
      image?: string;
      isAdmin?: boolean;
      isUser?: boolean;
      isSuperadmin?: boolean;
      firstName?: string;
      lastName?: string;
      phone?: string;
    };
  }
}

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      issuer: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ISSUER!,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
      session.user.sub = token!.sub;
      session.user.id = token!.id_token;
      session.user.access_token = token!.access_token;
      let roles = JSON.parse(
        Buffer.from(token.access_token!.split(".")[1], "base64").toString()
      ).realm_access.roles;
      session.user.isAdmin = roles.includes(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN
      );
      session.user.isUser = roles.includes(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ROLE_USER
      );
      session.user.isSuperadmin = roles.includes(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ROLE_SUPERADMIN
      );
      let access_token = JSON.parse(
        Buffer.from(token.access_token!.split(".")[1], "base64").toString()
      );
      session.user.firstName = access_token.given_name;
      session.user.lastName = access_token.family_name;
      session.user.phone = access_token.phone;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }: { token: JWT; account: any }) {
      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token;
        token.provider = account.provider;
        token.access_token = account.access_token;
        token.refresh_token = account.refresh_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    error: "/",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
  },

  events: {
    async signOut({ token }: { token: JWT }) {
      if (token.provider === "keycloak") {
        const logOutUrl = new URL(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`
        );
        const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
        const header = new Headers();
        header.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlencoded.append("refresh_token", token?.refresh_token!);
        urlencoded.append("client_id", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_ID!);
        urlencoded.append(
          "client_secret",
          process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET!
        );

        try {
          const response = await fetch(logOutUrl.toString(), {
            headers: header,
            method: "POST",
            body: urlencoded.toString(),
          });
          if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text(); // Get the error response as text
            console.error("Logout failed:", response.status, errorText);
          } else {
            // Check if the response is JSON
            const contentType = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
            if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
                const resp = await response.json();
                console.log("Logout successfully", resp);
            } else {
                console.error("Logout response is not JSON:", await response.text());
            }
        }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Logout failed:", error);
        }
      }
    },
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

File: src/app/sessionproviderwrapper/sessionproviderwrapper.tsx
'use client'

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

// Wrapping the app's components with SessionProvider ensures that session data is available throughout the app.
const SessionProviderWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {

    return (
        <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default SessionProviderWrapper

File: src/app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import SessionProviderWrapper from '@/components/auth_provider_wrapper'
import SessionHandler from '@/components/sessionHandler'
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'
import CreateUserApi from '@/components/create_user'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "assessIt",
  description: "",
  icons: {
    icon: "/favicon.ico",
  },
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <SessionProviderWrapper>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={`{inter.className}`}>
          <SessionHandler>
            <CreateUserApi />
            <Toaster position="bottom-center" />
            {children}
          </SessionHandler>
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProviderWrapper>
  )
}


Question:
I have set up my Next.js application with NextAuth and Keycloak as shown above. However, I am facing issues with the authentication flow.

Are there any common pitfalls I should be aware of when integrating Keycloak with NextAuth?

Is there anything wrong with the way I am handling tokens and session data?

How can I properly debug the authentication process?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
